# How we can debug a signed apk without having source code?

Tags: android, debugging, apk

I want to ask if there is a possibility to debug a release apk without having source code and how we can prevent user to do this action ?

I thought that I can't debug an apk without a source code ( manifest has by default **android:debuggable="false"**) until I sent it to a client and he asks me to disable debuggable mode because he got this issue . I try to reproduce the problem and I'm thinking if he did a reverse engineering.

Comment: Not possible to debug without source code

Comment: @Imen, you can't debug an apk without source code, however an arr file can be debug by importing it to a project.

Comment: what is an arr file ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can debug an already signed APK with a number of different tools. Most approaches would be considered a form of reverse engineering. At a high level, a common approach (for dynamic "live" debugging) would be to:

1. Use [APKTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to enable debugging via the property in the AndroidManifest.xml. Align and sign the newly modified APK.
2. Use [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) to push the new "debuggable" APK to the device/emulator.
3. Use a debugger such as [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) (NDK includes a gdbserver with the arm toolchain).

It's worth mentioning that static analysis can be an option too, whereby the APK could be unpacked and decompiled to SMALI/Java.

There are a number of tools available to help reverse and debug APK's. Some I use frequently are; dex2jar, JDGUI, APK Studio, JEB, IDA Pro, VisualGDB.

Comment: it would be helpful if you added more details about how to use GDB

Comment: @Bouh I partly agree. The question was pretty broad. Learning to RE and use GDB is quite specific and depends on a myriad of factors. In my experience of RE; static analysis has far more importance, hence the list of tools. When having to live debug APK's I will usually use IDA on Windows and configure GDB there for remote debugging. If you have a particular issue getting GDB working then feel free to post it and send me a link. If you want to explore IDA, here's a link https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1343.shtml

Answer (score 17):

You can debug APKs without having source code, using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger) 3.0 and higher

- First make sure to [Enable Debugging](https://www.evilsocket.net/2017/04/27/Android-Applications-Reversing-101/#Debugging)
- > To start debugging an APK, click **Profile or debug APK** from the Android
  >   Studio Welcome screen. Or, if you already have a project open, click
  >   **File > Profile or Debug APK** from the menu bar. In the next dialog
  >   window, **select the APK** you want to import into Android Studio and
  >   click **OK**.

[image]

**Some prevention tricks against debugging:**

**1. Checking the Debuggable Flag in ApplicationInfo**

The `android:debuggable` flag in the Android Manifest determines whether the JDWP thread is started for the app. Its value can be determined programmatically, via the app's ApplicationInfo object. If the flag is set, the manifest has been tampered with and allows debugging.

```
public static boolean isDebuggable(Context context){
    return ((context.getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0);
}
```

**2. isDebuggerConnected**

The Android Debug system class offers a static method to determine whether a debugger is connected. The method returns a boolean value.

```
public static boolean detectDebugger() {
    return Debug.isDebuggerConnected();
}
```

The same API can be called via native code by accessing the DvmGlobals global structure.

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_test_debugging_DebuggerConnectedJNI(JNIenv * env, jobject obj) {
    if (gDvm.debuggerConnected || gDvm.debuggerActive)
        return JNI_TRUE;
    return JNI_FALSE;
}
```

**3. APK Signatures check**

If APK is resigned, its signature would have changed. Check that against your original APK signature.