# Temporarily change text in an Android app

Tags: android, inspect

How can I inspect and edit text in an Android app running on my device.
Like we normally do on a web browser. It's just for the sake of a screenshot.

I've tried Appium UIAUTOMATER, but none of that lets me to edit that info.

Comment: If you don't have the source code see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784776/how-we-can-debug-a-signed-apk-without-having-source-code). This, however, might not be what you want or could be to big of an effort. As El Stepherino put it, it will never be as easy as just pressing ```inspect element```.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that.

With a web browser, you can edit whatever the browser has loaded from the remote web server.  This includes ant HTML and CSS pages, as well as Javascript files.  The web browser can - with the right plugins - allow you to change the content of these files and thus alter the web app's behavior locally, as you already know.

The above is possible because HTML, CSS and Javascript are interpreted by the browser.

You cannot do the same with a native Android App, which is built using compiled languages.  I'm sure there are tons of tools out there that can allow you to reverse-engineer an Android App but even then, you'd have to rebuild the App and reinstall.